# I can't deploy a contract with payable function

Tags: solidity, payable, revert

I am a total beginner and I just started the Patrick Collins's course on youtube.

I apologize for my stupid question but I didn't find similar topic and I have been struggling with this issue for 2 hours, so I'm asking your help.

So the course was introducing the "payable word" on Solidity and, following the course, I got this simple code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.6.6 <0.9.0;

contract FundMe{

    function Fund() public payable{

    }
}
```

And the teacher started deploying the contract, sending something, like that: https://www.noelshack.com/2023-15-2-1681228558-image-2023-04-11-175557860.png

If i put 0 in the Value field, it works. But as soon as I try to send something, I have this error:

```
creation of FundMe pending...
creation of FundMe errored: VM error: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
[vm]from: 0x5B3...eddC4to: FundMe.(constructor)value: 1 weidata: 0x608...30033logs: 0hash: 0xdb7...26d98
```

I really don't understand it as my test account has 100 Ether..

I probably missed something obvious, I feel idiot but I really don't manage to fix it

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to send the Ether while you are deploying the contract.

First, deploy the smart contract using the Deploy button, then call the `Fund()` function specifying the amount you want to send to the contract :)

- Step 1: Deploy

[image: Deploy smart contract from Remix]

- Spet 2: Specify amount and call `Fund` function

[image]

As you can see from the labels, the deploy function is not payable while the Fund function is!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're attempting to send funds while deploying the contract, specifically when pressing the "Deploy" button. To properly deploy the smart contract, you should not indicate any value. Once the contract is deployed, you can test the function in the "Deployed Contract" section by adding a value as you did previously:

[image]

To test this function, you will need to add a value as you have done before.
I hope this helps, and feel free to ask for clarification if needed.